# Include FMDatabase from Mapbox

Tags: ios, mapbox

I am trying to use FMDB in my application. I am also using Mapbox framework for iOS. The problem I am having is that I get a linker error if I include the fmdb files separately. How can I access the FMDatabase.h from the Mapbox framework?

Comment: Thank you, brother. The linker error went away. The feature will tell if the files correspond. :)

Comment: @AndyH- How did you solve this error?

Comment: I used Rob's answer. He moved it from comment to answer I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider including the FMDB header (`.h`) files, but not the `.m` files. That will ensure that you won't have duplicative FMDB linker references, but by including the `.h` files, you'll be able to avail yourself of FMDB yourself. You might want to be careful that your header files correspond to the same version of FMDB as what Mapbox used.